# create an unary_function functor for non-static member function

Tags: c++, stl, functor

The code should explain my difficulty. Though the code itself is quite meaningless, I'm planning to add containers in MyClass, and use algorithms with member functions.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass() { a = 0; }
        ~MyClass() {}
    private:
        int a;
        bool tiny_test (int);
        int Func();
};

bool MyClass::tiny_test (int b)
{
    return a == b;
}

int MyClass::Func()
{
    // does not compile
    (mem_fun(&MyClass::tiny_test))(this);

    // commented below is another attempt, also no success
    //mem_fun1_t<bool, MyClass, int> tmp_functor = mem_fun(&MyClass::tiny_test);
    //tmp_functor(this);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot! Btw, I'm not using a static member function, simply because I believe it must work for non-static member functions.
P.S. Eric, Jarod42, thanks for prompt replies!

Comment: Note that `std::mem_fun` is deprecated since C++11 and removed in C++17 (in favour of `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind`).

Answer (score 0):

```
bool MyClass::tiny_test (int b)
{                     // ^^^^^ You missed this argument
    return a == b;
}
```

Try this:

```
// Supply one more argument. E.g., 3
(mem_fun(&MyClass::tiny_test))(this, 3);
```